# Replicate ipython history behaviour in Emacs

Tags: python, comint, ipython

Say, we've entered the following in the normal ipython shell.

```
In [1]: 1+1
Out[1]: 2

In [2]: 1+2
Out[2]: 3

In [3]: 2+4
Out[3]: 6
```

If I now enter:

```
In [4]: 1+
```

and press the `up` arrow key, ipython will offer `+1` and `+2`, i.e. I can skip over `2+4`. How do I replicate this behaviour using Emacs' ipython shell (IPy mode).

Comment: have you looked at this question? http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12628/how-to-go-through-command-history-based-on-whats-been-typed-matlab-style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which `ipy mode`, You are referring. I use `ipython` shell which comes with elpy. It also has the same problem.

By default <kbd>up</kbd> arrow (or <kbd>M-p</kbd>) are bind to `(comint-previous-input ARG)`. So no matter what You have at cursor, it just shows the previous input.

There is another function called `(comint-previous-matching-input-from-input N)` which basically gives the previous matching input for the input at cursor. It is bind to <kbd>C-c M-p</kbd>.

So if type something and press  <kbd>C-c M-p</kbd> it takes to previous match.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for (indeed, I was refering to `ipython`)